# Wait for response from Retrofit 2 asynchronous call

Tags: android, google-maps, http, asynchronous, retrofit2

in my Android inside an activity I have an asynchronous call to a google maps API inside a method see the code below :

```
public void reverseGeocode(String lat, String lng) {

        String geocodeApiUrl = getUrl(lat, lng);
        GoogleService googleService = GoogleServiceBuilder.buildService(GoogleService.class);
        Call<Address> geocodeRequest = googleService.geocodeAddress(geocodeApiUrl);


        geocodeRequest.enqueue(new Callback<Address>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Address> call, Response<Address> response) {

                if (response.errorBody() == null) {
                    if (response.body().getResults().length > 0) {
                        if (response.body().getResults()[0].getFormatted_address() != null) {
                            dropOffAddress = response.body().getResults()[0].getFormatted_address();
                        }


                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AdressPicker.this, "An error has occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Address> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(AdressPicker.this, "An error has occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

this method is called inside the Google map marker 's **onMarkerDragEnd** callback function , see code below :

```
@Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

                double lat = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                double lng = marker.getPosition().longitude;
                reverseGeocode(String.valueOf(lat), String.valueOf(lng));
                marker.setSnippet(dropOffAddress);
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                editor.putString("dropOffAddress", dropOffAddress);
                editor.putString("lat", String.valueOf(lat));
                editor.putString("lng", String.valueOf(lng));
                editor.apply();
            }
```

The problem here is the first time when I move the marker the **reverseGeocode** method is called but it is not awaited and the **onMarkerDragEnd** continue its execution and puts null inside the value of the **dropOffAddress**  variable which is intended to be displayed inside the snippet of the marker.

My question here is HOW to WAIT for the reverseGeocode method'is response inside **onMarkerDragEnd** before continuing executing ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only thing you. need is marker, just pass it as a parameter in your retrofit api call something like this.

```
public void reverseGeocode(String lat, String lng, Marker marker) {

    String geocodeApiUrl = getUrl(lat, lng);
    GoogleService googleService = GoogleServiceBuilder.buildService(GoogleService.class);
    Call<Address> geocodeRequest = googleService.geocodeAddress(geocodeApiUrl);


    geocodeRequest.enqueue(new Callback<Address>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Address> call, Response<Address> response) {

            if (response.errorBody() == null) {
                if (response.body().getResults().length > 0) {
                    if (response.body().getResults()[0].getFormatted_address() != null) {
                        dropOffAddress = response.body().getResults()[0].getFormatted_address();
                         applyGeoCode(marker)
                    }


                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AdressPicker.this, "An error has occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Address> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(AdressPicker.this, "An error has occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

now from here call a method passing the marker

```
public void applyGeoCode(Marker marker){
      double lat = marker.getPosition().latitude;
      double lng = marker.getPosition().longitude;
      marker.setSnippet(dropOffAddress);
      marker.showInfoWindow();
      editor.putString("dropOffAddress", dropOffAddress);
      editor.putString("lat", String.valueOf(lat));
      editor.putString("lng", String.valueOf(lng));
      editor.apply();
}
```

and call like this

```
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            reverseGeocode(String.valueOf(lat), String.valueOf(lng), marker);
        }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it ddin't  work , i am unable to access the marker outside the  OnMapReady function which causes the marker.setSnippet(dropOffAddress);
marker.showInfoWindow();  not to work

Comment: you can store the reference if needed once onMapReady get's called, did you tied? and access it later

Comment: Thank you , I made a mistake  , your solution is OK

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CountDownLatch` from the java.utils.Concurrent class.
Here is an example:

```
public class DoSomething {
    private Address dropoffAddr;
    private CountDownLatch dropoffAddrLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public void getAddressCallback(Address addr) {
        dropoffAddr = addr;
        dropoffAddrLatch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        //your stuff
        reverseGeocode(...); //you should call getAddressCallback once you have everything
        dropOffAddrLatch.await(); //this will wait until getAddressCallBack has returned,
                                  // you can call dropoffAddrLatch.countDown() wherever you want.
        //finish your stuff
    }
}
```